# Vue Can Paypal Sandbox Accounts Make Real Transactions on New Website

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I finished my app and I am planning to host it online. Can my clients use sandbox accounts to make real transactions? This is my first time developing an app and making it have real online transactions using Paypal. Does it have something to do with coding or I have to change a setting in Paypal itself?

Payments.vue

```
<template>
<div>
<div ref="paypal"></div>
</div>
</template>
mounted()
{
 const script = document.createElement("script");
          script.src =
            "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-MY-CLIENT-ID";
          script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
          document.body.appendChild(script);
}

methods: {
  setLoaded: function () {
      this.loaded = true;
      window.paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  //   description: this.product.description,
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: this.product.price,
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
          },
          onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();

            this.$q.notify({
              message: "Transaction Successful!",
              color: "green",
              actions: [
                {
                  label: "Dismiss",
                  color: "white",
                  handler: () => {
                    /* ... */
                  },
                },
              ],
            });
            let dateObj = new Date();
            let month = dateObj.getMonth();
            let day = dateObj.getDate();
            let year = dateObj.getFullYear();
            let output = month + "" + day + "" + year;
            this.$store
              .dispatch("SAVE_ENTRY", {
                username: this.username,
                password: this.password,
                confirmPass: this.confirmPass,
                access_id: output + this.newAccData,
                chosenSchoolId: this.chosenSchoolId,
              })
              .then((res) => {
                if (res.data === "Success1") {
                  this.$q.notify({
                    message:
                      "Transaction Successful! Please complete your registration process inside the website.",
                    color: "green",
                    actions: [
                      {
                        label: "Dismiss",
                        color: "white",
                        handler: () => {
                          /* ... */
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  });
                }
              });
            console.log(order);
          },
          onError: (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          },
        })
        .render(this.$refs.paypal);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a sandbox environment, on https://sandbox.paypal.com/ . You have to change the API endpoint to something like that. The sandbox uses separate accounts that can be made in the developer environment on PayPal API pages.

You should be able to set up sandbox accounts here:
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

However I dont think this is supposed to be a Javascript/Vue question, you'd want your PayPal API calls to take place on the server side as much as possible.

Comment: So wait, are my current codes acceptable? I just copied this from YouTube and it was working fine with the transactions. Do I need a server side for it or is this enough for making transactions on my site?

Comment: sorry Ive been a bit quick to judge, it seems you're using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#how-the-buttons-work which is safe to use on the client side. I'm not sure about the sandbox environment for this particular integration, you'll have to read through the documentation.

Comment: Based from what I've seen from the documentation, I only saw a few variables for the Client ID and secret as well as the URL for the Paypal API, but not a sample code. Can you pinpoint in the code where I should put the API code and how it should work? Sorry if it's any trouble,  I'm new at this.